# How to get client IP in Phoenix rest api

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have rest API in Elixir Phoenix and I want to log every requester client IP. Currently, I am using following code to get client IP:

```
conn.remote_ip |> Tuple.to_list |> Enum.join(".")
```

But, it gave me local IP `127.0.0.1`.

Then, I used following code:

```
remote_ips = Plug.Conn.get_req_header(conn, "x-forwarded-for")
remote_ip = List.first(remote_ips)
```

And it gave nil `x-forwarded-for`.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Are you running the app behind another server like nginx or varnish or anything else?

Comment: Yes, running on nginx.

Comment: Can you please include the nginx config you're using to route traffic to the Phoenix app?

Comment: ```proxy_redirect              off;
    proxy_set_header            Host            $http_host;
    proxy_set_header            X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header            X-Forwared-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_connect_timeout 60s;```

Comment: You have a typo `X-Forwared-For` -> `X-Forwarded-For`.

Answer (score 2):

Above solution works but I also had that problem and I found very complex solutions however I checked how [Plausible Analytics](https://github.com/plausible/analytics/blob/3a1c9e67cd67d5cb1fec68a4dee34f8cd0e056fd/lib/plausible_web/remote_ip.ex) had done it and here it is.

Source code from Plausible Analytics:

```erlang
defmodule MyAppWeb.RemoteIp do
  def get(conn) do
    forwarded_for = List.first(Plug.Conn.get_req_header(conn, "x-forwarded-for"))

    if forwarded_for do
      String.split(forwarded_for, ",")
      |> Enum.map(&String.trim/1)
      |> List.first()
    else
      to_string(:inet_parse.ntoa(conn.remote_ip))
    end
  end
end
```